# does channel maintains separate ledger?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

If there one ledger per channel. does that mean all the peer nodes arose different organisation have to be one channel.

Suppose, A sells 10 chicken shawarma to B in 80$ and A sells 10 chicken shawarma to C in 90$ and A wants to hide price details.

How would admin party now if A total amount in sales if A maintaining  a separate ledger for sales to different peers if they are on separate channel.

Answer (score 2):

**You define channels for the organizations which are interested to trade** with each other. **Each organization would have their own set of peers.** Some would be endorser, committer or anchor peer. Each peer would have a copy of the ledger.

Now, you would be instantiating the chaincode to a particular endorser peer for a given organization. For an instance, suppose there are 4 organizations A,B,C and D. All these are connected with one specific channel(**channel1**) where everyone can see all the transaction details. **Now, A and B** do have a special requirement where they **don't want to share their buying a specific product transaction details** with other organizations.

Therefore, **A and B would have a new channel(channel2) having an endorser peer**(*could be the same one which is there for channel1 having 2 chaincode installed*) which would **take care of their specific contract**. The data will be replicated to all the peers of only A and B.

Since C and D isn't the part of this special channel, this specific transaction will not be logged on their peers. They can just see whatever is logged by channel 1.

**How an admin would know about these?** Well, a network admin would always knows this as he would be the **one who is defining this network**. **He would be defining the channel and instanciating the chaincode over it**. So, *as per the design, an admin would always have an insight* of who can see what and what data could be stored over different ledgers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hope this helps. If it does please accept the answer. If it doesn't, feel free to comment so that I can help you in a better way.

Comment: Hi Nitish, thanks for you response. So, is it possible to have multiple chaincode instantiated on one single channel? Also, we can install multiple chaincode on single peer, so peer will have multiple ledger copies right.

Comment: In addition to above question, I am thining about how org C will see the total account balance of A if he wants to make a deal if A has multiple ledgers.

Comment: Only peers could have chaincode. A single peer could have multiple chaincode. There would be a single ledger throughout the network and all the peers would have a copy of it. For our special case of channel2, just A and B would have an entry over their peers about the transaction. This particular transaction will not be copied to C's peers. C can still communicate easily with A using channel1 which would take care of consensus by checking endorser peers of A and C.(if configured so)